# count data in current month - not 30 days back Postgres statment

Tags: postgresql

Ive this query which return data for 30 days from current date , need to modify it to return data for current month only not 30 days from current date

> SELECT count(1) AS counter FROM users.logged  WHERE createddate >=
>   date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE);

any tips how to tweak  this query , at based on Postgres

regards

Comment: Your query currently returns a count for the *current* month. On Jan 31st at 23:59:59 it'll give you all created accounts from Jan 1st 00:00:00 to then.

Comment: @Denis What im looking to modifiy here to give me count for the current montn only like count for data from 1st of Nov up to today ,

Comment: That's what your current query does. As I write this, `select date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE);` yields Nov 1st at midnight, i.e. what you want.

Answer (score 10):

Something like this should work.

```
SELECT count(1) AS counter
FROM users.logged
WHERE date_trunc('month', createddate) = date_trunc('month', current_date);
```

Comment: Works, but note that this wouldn't be able to use the index on createddate (assuming there is one), or indeed any index at all since `date_trunc()` is not immutable.

Answer (score 1):

It is already supposed to return the values in current month. Truncation does the conversion `10 Nov 2013 14:16 -> 01 Nov 2013 00:00` and it will return the data since the beginning of this month. The problem seems to be something else.

Comment: got your point i modified as you said and result : operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone == timestamp with time zone
LINE 1: ...(1) AS counter FROM snap.alert  WHERE createddate == date_tr...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: @MarcoDonJuan Sorry I fixed it. It is single `=`.

Comment: result become 0  which is strange

Comment: @MarcoDonJuan Are you sure you have a row with this `createddate = this month`?

Comment: ive row with createddate , im quite sure , when i change  = to => its count 30 days back and return the value but i set it to = its return 0

Comment: @MarcoDonJuan Actually I have just read the question again and your query is already supposed to return the current month (I thought it was `current <=` but it is not)

Answer (score 1):

> Ive this query which return data for 30 days from current date , need to modify it to return data for current month only not 30 days from current date

That's incorrect. Your query:

```
SELECT count(1) AS counter FROM users.logged WHERE createddate >= date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE);
```

returns all dates >= Nov 1st 00:00:00, in other words what you say that you want already. Or then, you've simplified your query and left out the more important bits — those that are broken. If not:

It *might* be that you've dates in the future and that you're getting incorrect counts as a result. If so, add an additional criteria in the where clause:

```
AND created_date < date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) + interval '1 month'
```

It *might* also be that your sample data has a bizarre row with a time zone such that it looks like the timestamp is from this month but the date/time arithmetics land it last month.

Answer (score 0):

This is will give you data for the current month only. I try to extract `month` and `year`. The last step is you can compare created date against current date-time.

```
SELECT count(1) AS counter 
FROM users.logged 
WHERE 
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM createddate) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM current_date)
    AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM createddate) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM current_date);
```